# Сформировать квадратную матрицу порядка N по заданному образцу

Tags: c++, массивы

Даны числа а1, а2, … аn. Сформировать квадратную матрицу порядка n по заданному образцу:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот примерный код, что дальше делать не знаю.

```
int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int n;
    cout << "Введите порядок квадратной матрицы: ";
    cin >> n;

    int** arr = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = new int[n];

    cout << "Введите а1, а2, ... , a" << n << " : ";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << "Введенный массив: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(4) << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: У вас во второй строке ошибка? После a_{n-1} должно идти a_n, а не a_{n-2}?

Comment: Ошибки нет, взгляните на диагонали

Comment: Это вы взгляните - еще раз, вторая строка вашей матрицы. Во всех строках идут 1 2 3 ... n-2 n-1 n - и только во второй строке у вас идет n-1 n-2 1. Увидели? Ну, или по-другому - в побочной диагонали везде a_n, кроме элемента во второй строке.

Comment: Наверное опечатка, задание препод давал, а объяснить как написать код не удосужился

Comment: Я о том и говорю, что опечатка/ошибка/etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все очень просто. Если обозначить матрицу как `b`, то

```
b[i][j] = a[(i+j)%n+1]
```

Если, конечно, нумерация `b` - как принято в C/C++ - с нуля, а вот `a` - как в условии - с 1.

Если и `a` нумеровать с нуля - просто не нужно `+1`.

Все!

Код сами напишете?

Можно просто ввести все a<sub>i</sub> в первую строку матрицы, а остальные строки получить сдвигом влево.

Типа

```
for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    b[i][j] = b[i-1][(j+1)%n];
```

Вот, по просьбам трудящихся весь код ввода:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> arr[0][i];

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        arr[i][j] = arr[i-1][(j+1)%n];
```

Comment: Опять мой аватар кому-то активно не нравится, что верный ответ минусует? :)

Comment: Я новичок ещё, не особо понял, если не трудно, можете короткий отрывок написать, как это в целом выглядит?

Comment: Теперь понятно, спасибо, + поставить не могу, репутации не хватает)

Comment: Принять ответ (птичка слева от него) можете? :)